# Any way to detect if a browser halts repainting on scroll?

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, responsive-design, repaint

I continuously run into this issue when designing sites that have scroll-based events (animation, parallax, etc etc etc).

Is there any reliable to test if a browser halts repainting on scroll, so I can better tailor my interactions to the platform?

Comment: Not unless perhaps you're writing a browser extension; I know Chrome has a repaint performance timeline/graph feature, but I don't know if you can access it programmatically. It's highly browser specific and best done manually. Otherwise you're left with measuring drops in framerate using something like `requestAnimationFrame()`.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can check paint actions.

> Chrome > Developer Tools (f12) > Timeline

Tick the

> paint checkbox

then record start recording and do actions in the browser, like you mentioned scrolling. Then click the record button again to stop. Later you can see each and every event, every frame, how chrome painted your screen.

Comment: This is cool for debugging, but I'm looking for a way to detect this sort of thing using JS in browser, across platforms, so I can tailor the UX on the fly.

Comment: No, I am not sure any JS can do such things. it really cant get such data from the browser.